# How to add my brand logo for Yahoo email?

Tags: email, yahoo, yahoo-mail

*Note: I asked [the same question](https://serverfault.com/questions/1062934/how-to-add-my-brand-logo-for-yahoo-email) on *serverfault*, but it got closed as off-topic.*

I want to include my brand logo in my emails. My brand logo does not appear in Yahoo mailbox, but I have noticed that some companies, like the example below, have included their brands in the email.

[image]

### Here is what I have tried:

I have added BIMI record for our website:

https://www.mailkit.com/resources/bimi-inspector/shopless.co.nz

I have also added Gravatar for our emails:

[image]

I have also contacted Yahoo support, weeks ago, and followed up a couple of times. All they told me is that "their engineers are working on BIMI issue".

When I check the example above (Kijiji) I noticed that they neither have a BIMI record, nor a Gravatar. But their logo is still showing up in Yahoo. They must have tried a different approach that I am not aware of?

---

*PS: I opened the email that I received from Yahoo support, in Yahoo mail, and their own emails didn't have any brand!*

Answer (score 1):

Yahoo has additional requirements to display a logo in their inbox. For example, the email address must have sufficient reputation and engagement. Yahoo won't disclose how these metrics are measured, but there is a list of things that influence "reputation" on their [FAQs](https://senders.yahooinc.com/faqs) page.

Here are the rest of the additional requirements:

- The email address must use a department name and not a personal name.
- The email address must have a history of sending emails to a large volume of recipients.
- The email address must not have been marked as spam by many users.

**For everyone else:** 
First, you will need complete the BIMI specification. Then, you will need to complete any additional requirements that each email service provider may have to display the logo in their inbox. This [tutorial](https://medium.com/p/77d713cb9e45) walks you through the process and explains everything you need to know.

**BIMI:** 
[Tutorial](https://medium.com/p/77d713cb9e45) 
[Inspector](https://bimigroup.org/bimi-generator/)

**BIMI (Yahoo):** 
[Overview](https://senders.yahooinc.com/bimi) 
[Best Practices](https://senders.yahooinc.com/best-practices) 
[FAQS](https://senders.yahooinc.com/faqs)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure about Yahoo as I personally do not use it nor have I ever tried to add a logo to a email before but yahoo and gmail tend to have similarities and I found a few links on the net that might help with your situation.

https://www.freelogoservices.com/blog/2018/02/15/how-to-add-a-logo-to-your-email-signature/

[https://www.graphicsprings.com/blog/view/how-to-add-a-logo-to-your-email-signature-gmail-yahoo-outlook-and-more#:~:text=Navigate%20back%20to%20your%20Yahoo,save%20and%20you%27re%20done](https://www.graphicsprings.com/blog/view/how-to-add-a-logo-to-your-email-signature-gmail-yahoo-outlook-and-more#:%7E:text=Navigate%20back%20to%20your%20Yahoo,save%20and%20you%27re%20done)!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you are looking for can be achieved by changing your Yahoo account profile picture. So you need to put your logo as account profile pic. Usually in Gmail this happens by changing your account profile picture.

This link might be helpful to you:
https://help.yahoo.com/kb/update-yahoo-account-picture-sln25611.html

Comment: Thanks, but this is not a yahoo domain.